# Падение производительности после изменения material.color

Tags: unity3d, производительность, шейдеры

В моей игре, одновременно, на экране находятся от 30 до 200 юнитов, состоящих из 6 спрайтов.

Вздумалось мне реализовать подсветку юнитов. Союзных - одним цветом, вражеских 
- другим цветом.

Так как юниты состоят из нескольких спрайтов, то простая подсветка, типа подложить под главный спрайт еще один спрайт побольше, не применима. Решил писать шейдер.
Найдя основу в интернете и подправив на свой лад получилось это:

```
Shader "Custom/Sprite-Outline" 
{
    Properties
    {
        _OutLineSpread("Outline Width (_OutLineSpread)", Range(0,0.1)) = 0.007
        _Color("Outline Color (_Color)", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _ColorTint("Tint (_ColorTint)", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
        }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Fog{ Mode Off }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile DUMMY PIXELSNAP_ON
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                float4 color    : COLOR;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            fixed4 _ColorTint;
            fixed4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
            {
                v2f OUT;
                OUT.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN.vertex);
                OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                OUT.color = IN.color * _ColorTint;
        #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap(OUT.vertex);
        #endif
                return OUT;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _OutLineSpread;

            fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
            {
                fixed4 mainColor = (
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + float2(_OutLineSpread,_OutLineSpread)) + 
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord - float2(_OutLineSpread,_OutLineSpread))
                );

                mainColor += (
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + float2(-_OutLineSpread,_OutLineSpread)) + 
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord - float2(-_OutLineSpread,_OutLineSpread))
                );

                mainColor += (
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + float2(_OutLineSpread, 0)) +
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord - float2(_OutLineSpread, 0))
                );

                mainColor += (
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + float2(0, _OutLineSpread)) +
                    tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord - float2(0, _OutLineSpread))
                );

                if (mainColor.a > 0.1f)
                {
                    mainColor = _Color;
                }

                fixed4 addcolor = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;

                if (addcolor.a > 0.5f)
                {
                    mainColor = addcolor;
                }

                return mainColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
        Fallback Off
}
```

Так как спрайтов очень много, я ожидал просадку производительности, но, на удивление, все работает довольно быстро, пока......

...пока цвет обводки стоит по умолчанию. Как только я изменяю свойство material.color (один раз в функции Start), производительность очень сильно падает. На ПК это не сильно заметно, но на Мобильном устройстве фпс падает до уровня слайд шоу.

Почему так происходит? Неужели материалы так сильно грузят процессор, если изменять их свойства?

P.S. Если кто то предложит другой способ обводки юнитов, буду признателен. Но, все же, это не главный мой вопрос.

Comment: В чем именно проявляется проседание производительности? На чём смотрел? Чем измерял? Почему думаешь, что это именно от шейдера?

Comment: попробуй такой шейдер https://pastebin.com/U7YeyxTT  и вот этот туториал http://nielson.io/2016/04/2d-sprite-outlines-in-unity/  (там по идее правильная реализация изменение параметров через сам скрипт)

Comment: Смотрел через профайлер. Проседает именно на отрисовке. Проблему решил, меняя сам материал на другой(с заранее измененным цветом). Из этого и вывод что из за изменения свойства цвета материала. Про шейдер написал, так как, возможно, проблема в нем, ведь он ссылается на переменную с цветом.

Comment: А за ссылку спасибо), посмотрю как только время появится.

Comment: Если использовать MaterialPropertyBlock, пробема пропадает. Но я все еще не могу понять почему нельзя изменять значение цвета на прямую, ведь пользователь имеет доступ к свойству color.

Comment: Вообще тема с шейдерами - сложная и большая тема. Но в целом как раз и получается, что в твоем случае происходит копирование блока, который передается в отрисовку. То есть 200 юнитов - 200 копий. А в другом случае создается один блок и уже через скрипт он переиспользуется разными объектами. Как-то так

Comment: Еще важно тут (в рабочем правильном варианте) наличие **PerRendererData**. Это важно. Кстати можешь прочитать об этом здесь http://thomasmountainborn.com/2016/05/25/materialpropertyblocks/ ... Там в принципе написано то, что я написал чуть выше про копии и переиспользование, но чуть обширнее

Comment: Напиши как ответ, я его отмечу)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В целом, когда есть много много объектов, у которых хочется анимировать цвет или как-то с ним поэкспериментировать, то возникает желание написать вот так:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = ...
```

Легко, круто, идём валяться счастливыми на диванчике. 
Однако...возникает проблемка: для изменения цвета в шейдере *Unity* должен сказать *GPU*, что этот объект будет отображаться по-разному, и единственный способ, которым это может сделать, — изменить экземпляр материала. 
Из-за этого *Unity* создает **копию материала** при первом обращении к файлу `renderer.material` (если только этот рендеринг не является единственным, использующим этот материал). 
Эта **копия** в дальнейшем используется для этого средства визуализации.

Это означает, что если есть много копий, то и память съедается нехило. Вот пример когда используется один материал на все объекты (2500 объектов ~47kB памяти):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот, когда начинаются танцы с `renderer.material` (2500 копий и 6M памяти)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В *Unity* есть такая штука как **[MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)** - для скрипта 
и **[[PerRendererData]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/MaterialProperty.PropFlags.PerRendererData.html)** - атрибут для шейдера. Они работают **в связке**.

Если грубо говоря, то `PerRendererData` позволяет сказать, что надо задать на изменение материала для каждого объекта лишь то свойство, которое помечено этим атрибутом. При этом материал не копируется. 
А вот за счет скрипта и `MaterialPropertyBlock` происходит изменение того свойства.

Пример шейдера:

```
Properties 
{
    [PerRendererData]_Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
}
```

Пример скрипта:

```
public class TestMaterialPropertyBlock : MonoBehaviour {
    public Color Color1, Color2;
    public float Speed = 1, Offset;

    private Renderer _renderer;
    private MaterialPropertyBlock _propBlock;

    void Awake() {
        _propBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void Update() {         
        // Берем текущее значение свойств материала в renderer
        _renderer.GetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
        // Устанавливаем  новое значение для цвета
        _propBlock.SetColor("_Color", Color.Lerp(Color1, Color2, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * Speed + Offset) + 1) / 2f));
        // Сохраняем всё обратно в блок
        _renderer.SetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
    }
}
```

---

### Заметка:

Если в шейдере не поставить `[PerRendererData]`, то увы, но *Unity* создаст материал за вашей спиной и в итоге профита не будет

---

В целом какие выводы:

- можно на основе полученной информации переделать шейдер и пририсовать свой скрипт по изменению свойств.
- можно попробовать **не менять материал через скрипт**, а сделать несколько материалов для разных типов персонажей и просто сразу нацепить на них шейдер с нужным цветом (в теории должно работать без проседаний)
- можно воспользоваться скриптом и шейдером вот **[отсюдовочки](http://nielson.io/2016/04/2d-sprite-outlines-in-unity/)**, в котором делается по описанию выше:

  Шейдер:

  ```
  Shader "Sprites/Outline"
  {
      Properties
      {
          [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
          _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
          [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0

          // Add values to determine if outlining is enabled and outline color.
          [PerRendererData] _Outline ("Outline", Float) = 0
          [PerRendererData] _OutlineColor("Outline Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
      }

      SubShader
      {
          Tags
          {
              "Queue"="Transparent"
              "IgnoreProjector"="True"
              "RenderType"="Transparent"
              "PreviewType"="Plane"
              "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
          }

          Cull Off
          Lighting Off
          ZWrite Off
          Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

          Pass
          {
              CGPROGRAM
              #pragma vertex vert
              #pragma fragment frag
              #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
              #pragma shader_feature ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
              #include "UnityCG.cginc"

              struct appdata_t
              {
                  float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                  float4 color    : COLOR;
                  float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
              };

              struct v2f
              {
                  float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                  fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                  float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
              };

              fixed4 _Color;
              float _Outline;
              fixed4 _OutlineColor;

              v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
              {
                  v2f OUT;
                  OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                  OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
                  OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                  #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
                  OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
                  #endif

                  return OUT;
              }

              sampler2D _MainTex;
              sampler2D _AlphaTex;
              float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

              fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture (float2 uv)
              {
                  fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);

                  #if ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
                  // get the color from an external texture (usecase: Alpha support for ETC1 on android)
                  color.a = tex2D (_AlphaTex, uv).r;
                  #endif //ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA

                  return color;
              }

              fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
              {
                  fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord) * IN.color;

                  // If outline is enabled and there is a pixel, try to draw an outline.
                  if (_Outline > 0 && c.a != 0) {
                      // Get the neighbouring four pixels.
                      fixed4 pixelUp = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + fixed2(0, _MainTex_TexelSize.y));
                      fixed4 pixelDown = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord - fixed2(0, _MainTex_TexelSize.y));
                      fixed4 pixelRight = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord + fixed2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, 0));
                      fixed4 pixelLeft = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord - fixed2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, 0));

                      // If one of the neighbouring pixels is invisible, we render an outline.
                      if (pixelUp.a * pixelDown.a * pixelRight.a * pixelLeft.a == 0) {
                          c.rgba = fixed4(1, 1, 1, 1) * _OutlineColor;
                      }
                  }

                  c.rgb *= c.a;

                  return c;
              }
              ENDCG
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  скрипт

  ```
  using UnityEngine;

  public class SpriteOutline : MonoBehaviour {
      public Color color = Color.white;

      private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

      void OnEnable() {
          spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

          UpdateOutline(true);
      }

      void OnDisable() {
          UpdateOutline(false);
      }

      void Update() {
          UpdateOutline(true);
      }

      void UpdateOutline(bool outline) {
          MaterialPropertyBlock mpb = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
          spriteRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(mpb);
          mpb.SetFloat("_Outline", outline ? 1f : 0);
          mpb.SetColor("_OutlineColor", color);
          spriteRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(mpb);
      }
  }
  ```